# php next/current operations take a long time

Tags: php, arrays, performance, function

I have a problem with next and current array operations which take a long time, much longer than a foreach on a long array.  Are there some functions I can use which do the same but quicker?

Comment: is there a reason you aren't using foreach?

Comment: are you able to use the usual for? It's probably the fastest.

Comment: why not just use a foreach then...

Comment: Can you provide a reproduceable use-case?

Comment: Yeah, sorry typed this in a little of a rush but basically I'm trying to make a memcache/mysql way of going through an array. 
So currently I have while($row = my_function($mysql_result)) - the result might be a mysql result or a memcached array - just had a look here and think I have a good idea of where to go next, sorry for any inconvience. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the size of your array, you could try the [SplFixedArray](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php).
In general the Spl implementations are highly optimised and pretty fast.